# How to access a variable defined in an included file with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form like this:

**my_file.html:**

```
<form name='first_form'>
  ...
</form>
<div ng-include="'/includes/second_form.html'"></div>

<a ng-click="myLog(first_form);myLog(second_form);">Submit</a>
```

**/includes/second_form.html**:

```
<form name='second_form'>
  ...
</form>
```

In can pass `first_form` to my controller, but not `second_form`. (myLog does a console.log).

How can I access the form in the included file ? Is there a better way to have access to the forms in angular ?

Comment: Due to how scope inheritance and the FormController work, there is no simple way to access the inner form! This is indeed a nuiscance. I am always putting a controller in the same level as the form in order to access it. You could expose it to a parent using co-operating directives (a parent that receives the form and a child on in the inner form that `require`s the controller of the parent directive and provides it with the form).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I am new to angularjs. Could you guide me through your co-operating technique in a more detailed manner ?

Answer (score 0):

The principle is this:

Wrap `my_file.html` in a directive and include the second form as a directive too, e.g. as:

```
<div outer-directive>
    ...
    <div inner-directive></div>
    ...
</div>
```

The `outerDirective` must define a controller with a member method, e.g. `setInnerForm(form)`, that will store its `form` argument in the scope. The inner directive will require the parent controller and call this method as:

```
app.directive("innerDirective", function() {
    return {
        ...
        templateUrl: "/includes/second_form.html",
        require: "^outerDirective",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, outerController) {
            outerController.setInnerForm(scope.second_form);
        },
        ...
    };
}
```

A working demo of the principle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ABK5y/